# Using one collection from another in Cloud firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm still not 100% understand how Firebase Cloud works. In my text book I have the following code in the `onCreate` method:

```
Query query = db.collection("users")
            .document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .collection("list")
            .orderBy("_text", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

Also in the insert data button method I have:

```
db.collection("users")
    .document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .collection("list")
    .add(new Listitem(item))
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
        //code
    }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        //code
        }
    });
```

In my [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276240/understanding-how-to-set-up-a-cloud-firestore-db#61276355) I was asking about the authentication. Now I don't have the `set()` method so now I guess I do have to set the collection on the web. As I understand I need to create a collection called `list` and use it. Do I need to create a new cloud database `list`? If so, how should I do it? What should be the values? How does it being connected to `users`?

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand I need to create a collection called list and use it.

No, you don't need to create any list collection. Simply adding it to your reference, it's enough. It's automatically created for you.

> Do I need to create a new cloud database list?

No.

> What should be the values?

A collection does not contain values, only documents. The documents contain fields of different types that hold values.

> How does it being connected to users?

It's not connected in any way with the `users` collection. If you create a subcollection under a document, it doesn't implicitly create any parent documents. Sub-collections are not tied in any way to a parent document or collection. Bear in mind that Cloud Firestore documents and subcollections don't work like filesystem files and directories.